# Suppress KTable aggregation to intermediary topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to suppress a KTable after an aggregation.
It would be ideal to store them in a different topic when the time window is large (12, 24h etc) and tons of data can stack up.

`KTable<Windowed<String>, Object>` is the aggregation result's type.

Trying immediately after the aggregation calling suppress will cause an exception:

```
.suppress(Suppressed.<Windowed<String>>untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()
                            .withLoggingEnabled(Map.of())) 
                            .withName("IntermediaryAggregationsStore"))
```

The exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

In the initial configuration the String serde is used and It must stay that way, until the suppressing moment.

Is there any way of handling this?

```
            split.branch((key, value) -> true, branchConsumer(s -> s
            //.transform(TimestampTransformer::new)
            .map((key, someObject) -> new KeyValue<>(someObject.getId(), someObject))
            .groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.ofSizeAndGrace(Duration.ofMinutes(1), Duration.ofMinutes(1)))
            .aggregate(NewObject::new,
                    (key, value, aggregate) -> {
                        // do the mapping between SomeObject and NewObject
                        );
                        return aggregate;
                    }
            )
            .suppress(Suppressed.<Windowed<String>>untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()
                            .withLoggingEnabled(Map.of()))
                    .withName("someName"))
        // continue with what's left to do
```

Comment: Your default serde is Serdes.String, I assume? If so, you will want to override that from a WindowedSerde - https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/WindowedSerdes.html

Comment: I have added how the code looks like. 
Unfortunately I can't figure out through the api how to override the Serdes.String (you are right, that's the one used)

Comment: found it.. 
Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double()))
.suppress(....)
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`aggregate` function accepts a `Materialized` class](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/TimeWindowedCogroupedKStream.html#aggregate(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Initializer,org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized)) that you can override what serializer is passed forward to the suppression.

Comment: But if we pass the Materialized instruction to the aggregation will using suppress work afterwards?

The idea is that both Materialized and supressed can be configured with 'withLoggingEnabled'. Does one overwrite the other?

.suppress(Suppressed.<Windowed<String>>untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()
                        .withLoggingEnabled(new HashMap<>())))

Comment: I think the logging method for the materialized call is for its own statestore, and not related to the suppression. I'm not really sure, though